# Eclipse and OpenCV termination error + Solution

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, opencv, termination

I had a problem last days with Eclipse and OpenCV that prevented the pictures from being displayed. I could compile the code, generate the binaries and exe files, everything was ok, but when running the code (which should read a picture form the desktop, process it, and finally show it) nothing happened, and I got a termination error with -1,07....

Comment: This is not quite how this site works. It's OK to write a question and answer it yourself. -> [Self Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). But in this case, please, write the answer as answer as it is usual here. If in doubt, please, take the [tour] and consult [ask].

Comment: Thank you Scheff.  Good to know. That was my first post here.

Comment: @Safwan That's okay! You can still edit your question and then add an answer. If you do this, you can mark your question as "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding the bin file of both

...\mingw_w64\mingw64\bin
...\opencv\release_eclipse\install\x64\mingw\bin

to the environment path of eclipse found under: Run Configuration --> Environment --> add:

Name PATH

Variable C:\mingw_w64\mingw64\bin;D:\opencv\release_eclipse\install\x64\mingw\bin

C: and D: can be different in your computer

and, of course, adding the bin directories above to the windows system path.

If you have Qt installed in your computer and  successfully build your OpenCV for Qt you can also add its mingw64 file ( ...\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin) to the environment path of eclipse, it will also do the same job and solve the problem , the same as (C:\mingw_w64\mingw64\bin). Do not forget to add this Qt bin to the windows system path also.

Generally: I downloaded Eclipse, OpenCV and Cmake and built OpenCV susseccufly according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBamKg5_JKI&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=AleksandrIvanov). And I only had the problem described here.

I hope this could help someone :)